# One index page with <div> tags to separate page

Tags: iphone, css, jquery-mobile

**One index page with  tags to separate pages.**

One long HTML5 index page is used as the template, with different sets of  tags to separate header and footer bars on each page, using a clear file structure with all external files and links.

I know a jQuery can do that for you with index page, with different sets of  tags to separate each pages. But I'm stuck there with jQuery with a limited CSS3 styling freedom.

I'm using mostly CSS3 to style the page and JQuery for features and functionality instead.

I find jQuery approach of  tags are limited and I'm stuck with it.

Is there template **examples** or **code** available similiar to jQuery with header and footer and  tags for individual pages on a same index.html, not as anchor tags within a page?

Comment: multipage layout? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/multipage-template.html and http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

Comment: It is perfect!!! Is it possible to do jQuery page one and page two but with my own layout style in CSS3 and colours rather than jQuery style and colours? I see there is jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css on top of all JS. For example, use my own CSS instead of jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css or use both my own goes on top and jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css next?

Comment: jQM offers a Theme Roller: http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php but you can also override the CSS as well

Answer (score 0):

multipage layout?

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/multipage-template.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

Theme Roller:

- http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php

Comment: Yes. I've tried Themeroller. It is very useful but not the project I'm working on...it is custom style. I don't want to use themeroller buttons or style. It is too much to change the colour with own CSS. Is there reference online that I can use my own CSS instead of jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css or use my own CSS above jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css ?